# Callback after the record was created using e.force:createRecord

Tags: create-records, callback, force

Are there a way to add callback after the user created a record and clicked the **Save** button?

I am using a custom tab and custom components and open the **Create a record** modal window using `e.force:createRecord`, but I was not able to find out how to attach callback to the event.

I even found [this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003V4hQAE):

> Currently force:createRecord event does not accept any callback method or any after save event to handle custom action. Current force:createRecord always redirects to the newly created record. But in case if you want to just close the force:createRecord popup after save and refresh some other related component using the refresh is not possible.

So, is it really impossible? If so, what are current workarounds here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea has been created regrading the Callback method for force:createRecord event to redirect or refresh after save:-

```
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003V4hQAE
```

You have to go for Custom Lightning Component with same functionality without using  e.force:createRecord and you will be able to Callback after the record was created like:-

```
// Configure response handler
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.account", response.getReturnValue());
        } else {
            console.log('Problem getting account, response state: ' + state);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Then after the object will be changed I will have to go to the component and update it as well. Not a very good solution, but I agree that it seems to be the only one right now.

Comment: Exactly @iloveseven

Comment: Also I found [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_create_record.htm), but it will just facilitate the development of the custom component for a record creation.